# Create an Admin Project Within a Project

Tags: ios, xcode, project

I am still a noob to xcode so excuse me in advance. I am currently building an application that will require an admin app that updates the content to the application. I would like to incorporate this admin project within my existing project. Is it possible to add a new project to an existing project? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: usually the admin app is a web-service.

Comment: Yeah... I'm not sure why you'd even want to have Apple handcuffs on your admin control panel...

Answer (score 0):

Just have a button that leads to the admin panel and then make a ViewController or series of ViewControllers for the admin settings.  Only reveal the admin button when the user has admin privileges.